# WPF: Datagrid doesn't show Data

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, datagrid

I wanna show a List in my DataGrid
Unfortunately it doesn't show anything.

I know that their are many other threads with this topic but I couldn't apply them to my solution.

I tried several things:

`ItemSource = "{Binding}"`

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ContainerGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="187" Margin="10,222,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="772" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
<DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn  MinWidth="200"   >
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding containers}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

(MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```
ContainerGrid.ItemsSource = Container.getContainerList();
```

Thats my current DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ContainerGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="187" Margin="10,222,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="772" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding containers}"/>
```

Thats my Class:

```
    {
        private string id;
        private String name, version,status;
        public static List<Container> containers = new List<Container>();

        public Container() { }

        public Container(string id,String containerName, String version,String status)
        {
            this.id = id;
            name = containerName;
            this.version = version;
            this.status = status;
        }

        public static void AddContainerToList(Container container)
        {
            containers.Add(container);
        }

        public static List<Container> getContainerList()
        {
            return containers;
        }



    }
```

Thats how I add an object to the list:

```
Container.AddContainerToList(new Container(getID(line), getName(line), getVersion(line), getStatus(line)));
```

I don't see the mistake I did.
Also read about ObservableCollections but that would be a big amount of changes to do in my opinion.

Please Help :D

p.s. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id`, `name`, `version` and `status` must be defined as *public properties* for the `DataGrid` to generate a column for them, and for you to be able to bind to them.

You probably also want to rename them to comply with the C# naming conventions that use PascalCase for property names:

```
public class Container
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Version { get; private set; }
    public string Status { get; private set; }
    public static List<Container> containers = new List<Container>();

    public Container() { }

    public Container(string id, String containerName, String version, String status)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = containerName;
        Version = version;
        Status = status;
    }

    public static void AddContainerToList(Container container)
    {
        containers.Add(container);
    }

    public static List<Container> getContainerList()
    {
        return containers;
    }
}
```